# Saving long text in model a bad idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm saving the rss feeds in my model.  I'd say a typical text string is `261233` characters long and ~260kb.

With many models would this severely impact performance?

Comment: When you say you're saving the rss feeds what do you mean.  Storing each article in one db column?  Or parsing them into say author, content, summary, published date and storing those in separate columns?

Comment: Why do you store that data? How to you use that model beside reading that field, for example to you read many records, just to display its name in a list?

Comment: Storing it in one db column.

Comment: I parse it and save to other fields as well, just thought it would be a good way to check if the RSS model updating (if rss.xml == xml)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the text locally, there's nothing wrong with saving it in a model and persisting it to your database just like you'd typically do in Rails. Just make sure you use a :text field, and not :string.

As long as you don't perform expensive operations on your text fields, or keep several objects in memory at once (like storing all of your data in an array), there shouldn't be any performance issues.

Alternatively, you can store the text fields in a separate model and reference it from your RSS-model